# Infer type annotation from wrapped class

Tags: python, mypy

Given the following class relationship, I would like mypy to be able to infer that `x` is of type `int`. Generics and TypeVars do not seem to be of much help here. ParamSpec looked promising, but it is not supported by mypy yet. Any ideas?

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class A:
    def __call__(self) -> int:
        ...

class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, typ: T) -> None:
        self._typ = typ

    def __call__(self) -> ...:
        return self._typ()()

x = Wrapper(A)()
```

Comment: You probably want to replace T with `typing.callable[T]` for the `self.typ` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the generic [callback protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) to define a callable object. And covariant `TypeVar` to parameterize both protocol and generic wrapper class. Like so:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Protocol, Type

T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)


class CallableProto(Protocol[T]):
    def __call__(self) -> T:
        ...

class A:
    def __call__(self) -> int:
        ...

class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, typ: Type[CallableProto[T]]) -> None:
        self._typ = typ

    def __call__(self) -> T:
        return self._typ()()


x = Wrapper(A)()
# reveal_type(x)  # Revealed type is "builtins.int*"
```